# wrong redirect after signing in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cucumber

I have this controller.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in, :username => resource.username) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 end
end
```

and this step-defenitions for cucumber:

```
Given /^a user "(.*?)" exists$/ do |user_name|
    @user = User.create!(:username => user_name , :password => "tamara")
end

When /^he logs in$/ do 
  visit("/users/sign_in")
  fill_in('Username', :with => "roelof")
  fill_in('Password', :with => "tamara")
  click_button('Sign in')
end

Then /^he should see "(.*?)"$/ do |message|
  page.should have_content(message)
end
```

Everything works fine only after a successfull login I get redirect to the homepage and not to the login succceed page. So I don't see the flash message.

Roelof

Edit 1 : I checked the controller and resource_name and resource seems to have the right values.

Answer (score 0):

the standard DeviseHelper for after_sign_in_path_for is the signed_in_root_path

```
  # The scope root url to be used when he's signed in. By default, it first
  # tries to find a resource_root_path, otherwise it uses the root_path.
```

You can check your routes and scope , and even debug by duplicating the Devise signed_in_root_path into your ApplicationController with a debugger line

Answer (score 0):

By default, Devise's internal `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method first tries to find a valid {resource}_return_to key in the session, then it fallbacks to {resource}_root_path, otherwise it uses your root path route.

For instance, setting `user_root_path` would set direct path in the users scope after successful sign in (probably what you want):

```
# config/routes.rb
...
devise_for :users do
 get 'users', :to => 'users#show', :as => :user_root 
end
```

Or even:

```
# config/routes.rb
...
match 'user_root' => 'users#show'
```

Another way to override the redirect on successful login by overriding `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`:

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
...
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  # Put some path, like:
  current_user_path
end
```

Links for you to read:

- [How to: redirect to a specific page on successful sign in out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-out)
- [Method: Devise::Controllers::Helpers#after_sign_in_path_for](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/Helpers%3aafter_sign_in_path_for)
- [How To: Customize the redirect after a user edits their profile](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile)
- [How To: Change the redirect path after destroying a session i.e. signing out](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Change-the-redirect-path-after-destroying-a-session-i.e.-signing-out)

Comment: Hello, When I do your suggestions I see this error : https://gist.github.com/4050770

Comment: I solved that one but now I get a uninitialized constant UserController message. Which is wierd because Devise don't need a usercontroller.

Comment: "UserController" should be "UsersController". Sounds like a typo.

Comment: oke, but still the same. Without the change devise does not use a UsersController so I find it wierd that it uses it now